# Get the Year/Month/Day from a datetime in php?

Tags: php

I used `date('w', timestamp)` and `date('w', timestamp)` to know the day, `date('n', timestamp)` for months, etc.

Now I'm using datetime and I'd like to know what are the equivalent functions to get a day, a month, etc from a datetime.

PS: I know I could use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` in a SQL query but I prefer avoiding timestamps using in my code.

Comment: Are you saying you are using php's DateTime class? strtotime() on the datetime result should give you a timestamp to use date() on.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Use [DateTime](http://php.net/DateTime) with [DateTime::format()](http://php.net/datetime.format)

```
$datetime = new DateTime($dateTimeString);
echo $datetime->format('w');
```

Comment: Just another misdesign in PHP! Why are there no functions getDay(), getMonth(), getYear(), etc..? Or a function that returns an Array like getdate() does? What a shame that I have to use these cryptic characters which are not even intuitive. (w for day, where is the logic?) PHP is so FULL of misdesigns. It is really ugly to work with PHP.

Comment: @Elmue There are many things to blame PHP for and you can continue to do so. Or you can accept, that this was taken 1:1 from C. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf (search for `strftime`) You wonder, why "w" refers to the weekday? Surprising. At the end (90%) you usually don't want only the month, or day, but a formatted, locale-dependent date string. You will end on `format` anyway.

Comment: Taking something directly from C is bad implementation. It exposes the C internals to php developers.

Comment: PHP misdesign? Create your own wrapper! It's so easy to make and is only on-the-spot if  want it! The C(++) Libraries are very large and are incorporated in your code making an enormous the memory footage with functions you never use at all. 
And believe me I love C(++), but also PHP.

Answer (score 34):

Check out the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

Will output: `2000-01-01 00:00:00`

Comment: I set a constant called TIMESTAMPFORMAT equal to 'Y-m-d H:i:s'.  Comes in very handy working with DateTime

Answer (score -1):

Try below code if you want to use php loop to display

```
<span>
  <select name="birth_month">
    <?php for( $m=1; $m<=12; ++$m ) { 
      $month_label = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1));
    ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $month_label; ?>"><?php echo $month_label; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select> 
</span>
<span>
  <select name="birth_day">
    <?php 
      $start_date = 1;
      $end_date   = 31;
      for( $j=$start_date; $j<=$end_date; $j++ ) {
        echo '<option value='.$j.'>'.$j.'</option>';
      }
    ?>
  </select>
</span>
<span>
  <select name="birth_year">
    <?php 
      $year = date('Y');
      $min = $year - 60;
      $max = $year;
      for( $i=$max; $i>=$min; $i-- ) {
        echo '<option value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
      }
    ?>
  </select>
</span>
```