# How can I display hour and minute only Php from mysql database like(00:00)?

Tags: php, mysql, display, hour, minute

How can I display hour and minute only Php from mysql database like(00:00)?
Here is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$resualt = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($resualt) > 0)
{
    echo "<table class='tb'>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resualt)){
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['id']. "</td><td> " .$row['name']. " </td><td> " . $row['place']. " </td><td> " . $row['ddate']. " </td><td> " . $row['dtime']. " </td><td> ".$row['message']."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo `enter code here`"<table>";
}
else
{
    echo "there is no record.";
}
```

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the Year/Month/Day from a datetime in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247259/get-the-year-month-day-from-a-datetime-in-php)

Comment: Is this referring to the `dtime` column? What is an example value from that column?

Comment: dtime column shows me this: 02:01:00.0  but i want to show me 02:00 hh:mm only in the browser

Answer (score 2):

You query the time through MySQL with

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:%i')
```

For example

```
$query = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:%i') as time FROM table";
```

Then you can access it through `$row['time'];`

Comment: the time is not current time it is  a time which is already in the database , when i try your code i got this error "mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given"

Comment: Replace NOW() with ddate. Your error usually occurs when mysqli_query failed. Check if your table is correct. The sample query I showed you works for me fine and is syntaxically correct. Try to replace time to time123, eventually it's a reserved variable in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table has a datetime column, you can pluck the hour and minutes from it like this...

```
 SELECT HOUR( `datecol` ) AS HOUR, MINUTE( `datecol` ) AS MINUTE FROM table WHERE BLAH=blah
```

You can also select other things like ....

`WEEK` to get the week number of the year

`WEEKDAY` to get the day name of the week...